# interpreting a json string

Tags: json, wordpress, string

I have an object in my database following a file upload that look like this

a:1:{s:4:"file";a:3:{s:7:"success";b:1;s:8:"file_url";a:2:{i:0;s:75:"http://landlordsplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/23192643-threepersons.jpg";i:1;s:103:"http://landlordsplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/364223-two-female-stick-figures.jpg";}s:9:"file_path";a:2:{i:0;s:93:"/var/www/vhosts/landlordsplaces.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/23192643-threepersons.jpg";i:1;s:121:"/var/www/vhosts/landlordsangel.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/364223-two-female-stick-figures.jpg";}}}

I am trying with no success to parse extract the two jpg urls programmatically from the object so i can show the images ont he site. Tried assigning parse(object) but that isnt helping. I just need to get the urls out.

Thank you in anticipation of any general direction

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, but it isn't valid JSON. How is your database generating it?

Comment: In which programming language are you trying to do this?

Comment: To be honest I was not sure if it was a json object. That object is generated by Forminator a widely used Wordpress form generator. Ive copied the database entry verbatim, So to answer the question its a PHP progamming environment. Although I suspect the upload is Ajax. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is not a JSON string. It is a serialized PHP object. If this database entry was created by Forminator, you should use the [Forminator API](https://premium.wpmudev.org/docs/api-plugin-development/forminator-api-docs/#method-get_entry) to retrieve the needed form entry. The aforementioned link points to the `get_entry` method, which I suspect is what you're looking for (I have never used Forminator), but in any case, you should look for a method that will return that database entry as a PHP object containing your needed URLs.

Comment: Thank you very much John, You are right. Ive done some further research. And it is a Forminator API method that is the solution. I will explore that some more. I only want the URL from that string. But at least my nose is pointed in the right direction now. Its gping to be my first effort getting under the skin of WP plugin API and related methods. So I may not surface quickly from the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is ever of any help to anyone the answer to the question was based on John input. The API has the classes to handle that without needing to understand the data structure.

Forminator_API::initialize();

$form_id = 1449; // ID of a form
$entry_id = 3; // ID of an entry

$entry = Forminator_API::get_entry( $form_id, $entry_id );

$file_url = $entry->meta_data['upload-1']['value']['file']['file_url'];
$file_path = $entry->meta_data['upload-1']['value']['file']['file_path'];

var_dump($entry); //contains paths and urls

Hope someone benefits.

Answer (score -1):

```
function prepare_array_mysql( $array )
      {
    
        if ( !is_array( $array ) )
          return prepare_string_mysql( $array );
    
        $prepped_array = array();
    
        $empty = true;
    
        foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    
          if ( $value !== '' )
            $empty = false;
          $prepped_array[$key] = prepare_string_mysql( (string) $value );
        }
    
        return $empty ? '' : serialize( $prepped_array );
      }
    
      /**
       * prepares a string for storage
       *
       * gets the string ready by getting rid of slashes and converting quotes and
       * other undesirables to HTML entities
       * 
       * @param string $string the string to prepare
       */
   function prepare_string_mysql( $string )
      {
        return stripslashes( $string );
      }
```